# I cannot get jquery 'change' to work, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery

I have tried ".change" and ".live change" but with no success. The code below is one of the many I have copied from googled requests for examples. I believe I need to use the "live" change because in my code I dynamiclly create the input field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test change</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id='inurlprodcgs' type="url" name="urlprodcgs" autocomplete="off" required/>
</body>
    <script>
        if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
            alert("jQuery library is loaded!");
        }else{
            alert("jQuery library is not found!");
        }
        $("input[type='url']").live('change', function(e) {
            alert("hide");
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

As you can see I have tested to see if jquery is loaded.

Comment: don't you have a console in your browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because live is removed (*as you are using 1.10*)
use `.on()`

```
$(document).on('change',"input[type='url']", function(e) {
            alert("hide");
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test change</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id='inurlprodcgs' type="url" name="urlprodcgs" autocomplete="off" required/>
</body>
    <script>
        if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
            alert("jQuery library is loaded!");
        }else{
            alert("jQuery library is not found!");
        }
        $("input[type='url']").change(function(e) {
            alert("hide");
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Care to explain how this addresses the problem?  A block of code with no context isn't really an answer.

Comment: I used the same asker's code. just copy and paste, all it's working

Comment: Except for the part where the asker says "I dynamiclly create the input field."  Your solution doesn't use event delegation (which the original code does, or at least tries to do) and will only work for input fields which are part of the DOM when it initially loads.